# Django ORM: How to group on a value and get a different value of last element in that group

Tags: python, django, annotations, django-orm

I have been trying to tackle this problem all week but I just can't seem to find the solution.

Basically I want to group on 2 values (user and assignment), then take the last element based on date and get a sum of these scores. Below a description of  the problem.

With Postgres this would be easily solved by using the .distinct("value") but unfortunately I do not use Postgres.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
UserAnswer
- user
- assignment
- date
- answer
- score
```

So I want to group on all user / assignment combinations. Then I want to get the score of each last element in that group. So basically:

```
user_1, assignment_1, 2019, score 1
user_1, assignment_1, 2020, score 2 <- Take this one
user_2, assignment_1, 2020, score 1
user_2, assignment_1, 2021, score 2 <- Take this one
```

My best attempt is using annotation but then I do not have the score value anymore:

```
UserAnswer.objects.filter(user=student, assignment__in=assignments)
    .values("user", "assignment")
    .annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

Comment: how did you check if you have score or not? I do not see problem with your query. did you chack useranswer.score?

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. I did check it and it only returns the user, assignment and max date value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I had to use raw query rather than django's ORM.

```
subquery2 = UserAnswer.objects.raw("\
        SELECT id, user_id, assignment_id, score, MAX(date) AS latest_date\
        FROM soforms_useranswer \
        GROUP BY user_id, assignment_id\
    ")

# the raw queryset from above raw query 
# is very similar to queryset you get from django ORM query. 
# The difference is now we add 'id' and 'score' to the fields, 
# so later we can retrieve them, like below.

    sum2= 0
    for obj in subquery2:
        print(obj.score)
        sum2 += obj.score

    print('sum2 is')
    print(sum2)
```

Here, I assumed that both user and assignment are foreinkeys. Something liek below:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #assignment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Hee thanks for your response. I tried this one but unfortunately I still get only user, assignment and lastest_date back in a dictionary. Like this:

{'user': 1, 'assignment': 1, 'latest_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 19, 11, 0, 41, 2356, tzinfo=<UTC>)}

Comment: Hee man, I was really excited to try it but unfortunately it does not seem to work :(. The aggregate function counts all entries and not just the lastest_date ones.

Comment: sorry for your frustration. I updated my answer again. I hope you can give a try.

Comment: Not frustrated at all my friend :) thank you very much for all your help. Seems that your raw SQL does the trick!